# Lorentz transformation and projective transformation

Tags: geometry, representation-theory

Does anyone know how to show a projective transformation, i.e. a self-map of $\mathbb{RP}^n$, that takes

$S^{n-1}$={$x_0=0$}$/\sim$= $E^{n} /\sim$ (passing to the quotient in $\mathbb{RP}^n$) to itself, must be a Lorentz transformation, i.e. an element in Lorentz group $O(n,1)$?

I appreciate any hint or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Such a map has to preserve the [Hilbert metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_metric) on the open round ball and this  metric is a constant multiple of the hyperbolic metric (in the Klein model). Lastly, use the [hyperboloid model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model) of the hyperbolic space.

Comment: Does this mean not any projective transformation preserving$S^{n-1}$ can give rise to a Lorentz transformation, only for those preserving Hilbert distances?

Comment: @Dai: They necessarily preserve the Hilbert metric, since projective maps of projective lines preserve the cross-ratio.

Comment: Oh I see Thanks!